# getRuntime with pipe?

Tags: java, runtime

I want to execute the following command in a java program. But  it execute only the first part. the part after | is not executed

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" adb devices | tail -n +2 | cut -sf 1");

        process.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run that in a shell. Try this:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
        "/bin/sh",
        "-c",
        "adb devices | tail -n +2 | cut -sf 1"
});
process.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a script instead because Pipe itself is a part of the shell.

OR do something like this:

```
String[] commands = {
"/bin/sh",
"-c",
"ls /etc | grep release"
};

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
```