# How to get tomcat process id by the port and end that process

Tags: java, cmd, command

As per the below code, I'm trying to get tomcat process id by the port and end that process. I'm given this command in CMD is working but used to java doesn't work. I want to correct way please help me

```
try {
   Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
   Process proc = rt.exec("netstat -aon | find /i \"listening\"");
   InputStream stdin = proc.getInputStream();
   InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
   String line = null;
   System.out.println("<OUTPUT>");

    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
       System.out.println(line);

       System.out.println("</OUTPUT>");
       int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
       System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
} catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: There is nothing about [cmd] in your question.

Comment: You are writing to a console which is nothing to do with cmd.

Comment: your netstat -aon is executed like netstat -i because of the pipe. May be you could try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834656/getruntime-with-pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using windows it will be like this. I did not tested for linux but it should work I think if you check **commented** code.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = rt.exec("cmd /c netstat -ano | findstr 8080");
            //for linux
            //Process proc = rt.exec("/bin/bash -c netstat -ano |grep 8080");

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            System.out.println("<OUTPUT>");
            if ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                int processIdString = line.lastIndexOf(" ");
                String processId = line.substring(processIdString, line.length());
                System.out.println("Your process Id to Kill : " + processId);
                rt.exec("cmd /c Taskkill /PID" + processId + " /T /F");
                //for linux
                //rt.exec("/bin/bash -c kill -9 "+processId);

            }
            System.out.println("<OUTPUT>");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Occured");
        }
    }
```